# Difference between a stop and a step in OpenEXR?

Tags: graphics, openexr

What is the difference between a stop and a step in OpenEXR? Steps seem like sub-units of stops but beyond that I;m not sure of their relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Technical Introduction](http://openexr.com/TechnicalIntroduction.pdf):

> The range of normalized 16-bit floating-point numbers can represent
>   thirty stops of information with 1024 steps per stop. We have eighteen
>   and a half stops above middle gray, and eleven and a half below.
>   Denormalized numbers provide an additional ten stops at the low end,
>   with gradually decreasing precision.